# Styling rotated text in a stackpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

The first image is when my program is run:

[image]

The second is from Visual Studio:

[image]

To get the rotated text closer together I have placed in the TextBlock style a margin of -50.

My question is how can I compensate for the margin on the first Textblock to stop it disappearing?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTemplate">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="GridHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="rotatedText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-45" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-50,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Job Title" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Job_Title}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Department" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Department}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Company" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Company}" />

    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Company}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}">
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Modules</TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Customer Services</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Asset Management</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Works Management</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Project Management</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Rates Management</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Finance</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Human Resources</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Document Management</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >User Management</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedText}" >Configuration</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the first Module `TextBlock` a different Style having no negative margin.

Comment: thankyou! Do you also know a way to keep the fifth column the same width so you can't drag it wider? I can't see a MinWidth or MaxWidth.

Comment: Do you want to prevent only the 5th column from resizing or all columns?

Comment: Just set the `Width` Property of the column. Or do you want it to be automatically sized once and then prevented from resizing?

Comment: I would like to set the size once and prevent it from being resized.

Comment: So just use the `Width` Property - where is the problem? :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30971/discussion-between-inxs-and-hank)

Comment: the column is still able to be resized